# Postgres Match All in a List of Tuples

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's possible to find a record that matches any tuple from a list like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tags
WHERE (tags.namespace, tags.name) IN (('genre', 'Action'), ('content', 'Violence'));
```

But is it possible to find a record that matches *all* tuples from a list?

According to the Postgres documentation, this seems to be a job for `= ALL`:

> The result of ALL is "true" if **all** comparisons yield true (including the case where the array has zero elements). The result is "false" if any false result is found.

But strangely this operator does not seem to be compatible with a list of tuple values. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tags
WHERE (tags.namespace, tags.name) = ALL (('genre', 'Action'), ('content', 'Violence'));
```

... which gives me a syntax error at the first comma.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tags
WHERE (tags.namespace, tags.name) = ALL (ARRAY[('genre', 'Action'), ('content', 'Violence')]);
```

... which gives me a lovely `cannot compare dissimilar column types namespace and unknown at record column 1`.

Ideally I would like to keep the solution in a value list format.

Here is the schema of the `tags` table:

```
CREATE TYPE namespace AS ENUM ('genre', 'type', 'content', 'any');

CREATE TABLE tags (
    comic UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES comics ON DELETE CASCADE,
    namespace namespace NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(comic, namespace, name)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT t.comic
FROM tags t
WHERE (t.namespace, t.name) IN (('genre', 'Action'), ('content', 'Violence'))
GROUP BY t.comic
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;  -- 2 is the size of the list
```

The "2" is the number of tags being matched -- this version assumes (reasonably) that the tags are not duplicates for a given `comic`.

If you store the values in an array, you can use an array construct in the `WHERE` and the size of the array in the `HAVING`.